# Difference between list.sort and sorted(list)

Tags: sorting

Hi I am a beginner at Python and wondering why the below two code snippets give different outputs

Program-1

```
l1 = [235, 300, 666, 788, 1092]
l2=sorted(l1)
if l1 == l2:
    print("List is in ascending order")
else:
    print("Not in ascending")
```

Program-2

```
if l1 == l1.sort():
    print("List is in ascending order")
else:
    print("Not in ascending")
```

I expected both code to give output as "List is in ascending order". But Program-2 went into the Else branch. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

To simplify this issue, let's just look at the output of both sorting functions. Notice there is an output for `sorted()` and there is no output of `.sort()`

```
>>> l1 = [235, 300, 666, 788, 1092]
>>> sorted(l1)
[235, 300, 666, 788, 1092]
>>> l1.sort()
>>>
```

`sorted` returns a new list.  There is no output for `.sort()` because `.sort()` is a method on the list that sorts the list in place.

Sorted is helpful if you want to maintain immutability and not modify the existing list.

```
>>> l2
[300, 235, 1092, 666, 788]
>>> l3 = sorted(l2)
>>> l2
[300, 235, 1092, 666, 788]
>>> l3
[235, 300, 666, 788, 1092]
```

Answer (score 0):

**"l1.sort()"** does sort the list in ascending order but it return **None**. To put it another way, the xxx.sort() method just change the order of xxx but **doesn't return anything**. Meanwhile "l1" in the **if** branch is a **list**, the type doesn't match, so it will goes into the else branch. I hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`sorted(l1)` takes a list `l1` and returns a **new list** with its elements in ascending order. Note that **it doesn't do any modifications to the original list**.

`l1.sort()` will **sort the original list**, `l1`, and return `None`.

In Program-2, the line `l1 == l1.sort()` will check if `l1 == None` which, in this case, is `False`.

If you checked whether `l1 == sorted(l1)`, in this case, it would be `True`.

Answer (score -1):

`sort()` changes the list directly and doesn't return any value, that's why program 2 goes to the else branch

You can read more about it [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort)